# How to access record from database using linq-to-sql?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am working on `Linq to sql`. I have created a function to search records in database. My functions is :

```
    public IEnumerable<Record> SearchRecord()
    {
      var records = db.Records.Where(r => r.Name == Name && r.Date == Date 
                                                && r.Country == Country);
        return records;
    }
```

I am trying to handle the case where if any one property out of `Name, Date and Country` is null. In that case i just want to remove that filter and fetch records only on the basis of non-null properties.I don`t want to add if - else conditions. How can i do this ?

Comment: May be i am wrong. None of the below posts won't help if i correctly understand. I request please post the desired output with the small example. for time ignore Date field,
List<Record> Records = new List<Record>{ 
new Record { Name = "b", Country = "J"},// Record 1
new Record { Name = "a", Country = "J"},// Record 2
new Record { Name = null, Country = "J"},// Record 3
new Record { Name = "a", Country = "I"},// Record 4
};
If i wanna filter with Name = "a", Country = "J"
what is your expected?
My understanding is the result is Record 1 & Record 2 & Record 3

Is it Correct ???

Answer (score 1):

Since LINQ uses a Fluent interface you could do something like:

```
public IEnumerable<Record> SearchRecord()
{
    var records = db.Records;
    if (Name != null)
    {
        records = records.Where(r => r.Name == Name);
    }
    if (Date != null)
    {
        records = records.Where(r => r.Date == Date);
    }
    if (Country != null)
    {
        records = records.Where(r => r.Country == Country);
    }
    return records;
}
```

I'm pretty sure this results in a less optimal SQL Query sent to the database, but it's just to illustrate the usage of fluent api in this matter.

You could also cheat with `??`, like:

```
public IEnumerable<Record> SearchRecord()
{
    var records = db.Records.Where(r => r.Name == (Name ?? r.Name)
                                        && r.Date == (Date ?? r.Date)
                                        && r.Country == (Country ?? r.Country));
    return records;
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure the resulting sql will not be that different and perhaps even better than the cheating part since it will only filter on columns you actually use

Comment: Okay, I don't spend that much time looking at generated SQL queries so I wasn't sure. My concern was whether the filtering would be done after all records were loaded. But LINQ is lazy, so the query is only executed when you're doing something with the result, correct? In that case, the query can be compiled efficiently.

Comment: Indeed. It will only execute the query when you actually use (interate) the results.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for you, basically you're going to say that `if the parameter value is null OR the parameter value equals the row value then return me that row.`

```
public IEnumerable<Record> SearchRecord()
{
    var records = db.Records.Where(r => (Name == null || r.Name == Name)
                                        && (Date == null || r.Date == Date)
                                        && (Country == null || r.Country == Country));
    return records;
}
```